# Will deleting an Azure Container Service delete any related, provisioned resources?

Tags: azure, azure-container-service

I have an old Azure Container Service in my subscription, I've since migrated everything to AKS and I'd like to delete the old ACS.

As part of migrating to AKS I've reused a storage account related to the ACS cluster, and I'd like to be certain it's not going to be deleted when I delete the ACS cluster.

The documentations states that "The operation does not delete other resources created as part of creating a container service": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/container-service/containerservices/delete

But I've found some issues on Github that imply this may no longer be the case:

On [[ACS] Deleting an ACS instance only deletes the "logical" ACS resource](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/1310) someone commented that "This behavior is no longer the case--az acs delete removes all the expected resources"

And on [Deleting Container Service leaves provisioned resources around](https://github.com/Azure/ACS/issues/31) someone said in 2017 that "No ETA. but it is what we are actively working on [it]"

So is there way I can be certain what will be deleted when I delete the cluster? Or should I just back everything up and hope for this best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create a delete lock on the storage account and delete the ACS cluster. or I'd just delete ACS resources one by one. that way there is no risk of accidentally deleting your storage account.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. I did as you suggested and it looks like there wasn't any side effects from deleting the container service.